# os x MAMP apache virtual host laravel project misconfigured

Tags: apache, mamp, osx-elcapitan, virtual-hosts

MAMP is installed in a MacBook. I use the MAMP apache.

Based on many online resources, I have done the following:

1. I added `127.0.0.1   my-site.local` to file `/etc/host`.
2. I uncommented `Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` in `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf`.
3. In `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`, I added

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
           DocumentRoot "/Users/myname/laravel/mysite/public"
           ServerName my-site.local
           ServerAlias my-site.local
           <Directory "/Users/myname/laravel/mysite/public">
                   DirectoryIndex index.php
                   Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
                   AllowOverride All
                   Require all granted
           </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
4. In `/Users/myname/laravel/mysite/.htaccess` file:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

           Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
           RewriteEngine On
           #RewriteBase /

           # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
           #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
           #RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
           RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
           RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

           # Handle Front Controller...
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
           RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

           Require all granted

   </IfModule>
   ```

After all, `localhost`, `localhost/MAMP`, `localhost/phpMyAdmin`, all work, EXCEPT for `my-site.local`.
It shows `500 Internal server error. The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem Solved! 
Because the apache has been updated to **apache2.2**, 
in the Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf, 
change `Require all granted` to `Satisfy Any`.

That is it!

It took me two days to figure it out~